# Hibernate @Transient MappingException

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, transient

I am trying to add a Transient property to my Embeddable class. Here is what I have:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Embeddable
public class PackageProduct
{
    @Field
    private String productId;

    @Transient
    private Product product;
}
```

And PackageProduct is used in Package.java like this;

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass=PackageProduct.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<PackageProduct> packageProducts;
```

However, this throws the following exception: 
`Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: *.*.*.Product, at table: Package_packageProducts, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(packageProducts.product)]`

The exception is no longer thrown if I annotate my PackageProduct class with this:

```
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
```

I am trying to understand why it works with the class level @Access annotation. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In hibernate either you can apply all annotations on fields or methods, simultaneously mix use is not allow.To override this `@Access` is needed.In your product class if you are using such case, rectify this.

Comment: Thanks Amit for the input. Found that I have this on Product:
`@AccessType("property") private String id;`

However, what I don't get is PackageProduct works if I remove the `@Transient`, in which case I don't need the class level modifier.